# Why I get undefined method `each'?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

In application.rb I tried to read a YAML file:

```
config.before_configuration do
    env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
    YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
        end if File.exists?(env_file)
    end
```

but, I get this error:

```
/var/www/config/application.rb:26:in `block in <class:Application>': undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000007afb7f0> (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:53:in `before_configuration'
        from /var/www/config/application.rb:24:in `<class:Application>'
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

My yaml file:

```
LOAD_JS_FROM_AMAZON:no
RACK_ENV:production
S3_BUCKET_NAME:bucket_name
S3_CMS_BUCKET_NAME:cms_bucket_name
```

Comment: Looks like `YAML.load(File.open(env_file))` returns a `String` not an `Hash`. Can you post your yaml file?

Comment: Please see edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YAML.load(File.open(env_file))`

Your YAML is returning a `String` not a `Hash`

You need spaces between colon and value:

```
LOAD_JS_FROM_AMAZON: no
RACK_ENV: production
S3_BUCKET_NAME: bucket_name
S3_CMS_BUCKET_NAME: cms_bucket_name
```

Comment: Thank you, can't I use boolean values in yaml? I got this error: no implicit conversion of true into String (TypeError)

Comment: there's no problem using booleans in yaml. Just use `key: true` or `key: false`

Comment: I found that I have to ENV[key.to_s] = value.to_s in the above code